# Catch errors with angularjs and restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have this code :

```
MyService.one($routeParams.wuid).doGET('test').then(function(e){
    alert('ok');
}, function errorCallback(response){
    alert('error');
});
```

It calls an API i managed, but only the alert('ok') works, in the case of a 404 response, the callback isn't called i've a angularjs error in my console.

```
Error: c is undefined this.$get</e/A/v@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/restangular.min.js:8 Ad/e/k.promise.then/C@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:92 Ad/g/<.then/<@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:94 Bd/this.$get</h.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:102 Bd/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:100 Bd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:103 f@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:67 E@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:71 pd/</v.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:8888/client/app/js/libs/angular.min.js:72
```

I don't understand because [the official doc](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-handle-errors) says :

> How can I handle errors?
>
> Errors can be checked on the second argument of the then.
>
> Restangular.all("accounts").getList().then(function() {
>   console.log("All ok"); }, function(response) {   console.log("Error
>   with status code", response.status); });

Where am i wrong ?

Comment: Works perfectly in my code. Create a plunker or fiddle showing the error and I'm sure someone will assist.

Comment: thanks for your response. I posted the wrong piece of code, i've corrected. it's a doGet() instead of a get(), nothing else changes

Answer (score 0):

i found a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589752/angular-js-http-post-typeerror-cannot-read-property-data-of-undefined)
The problem comes from my interceptor which i started on yesterday and not finished:

```
myApp.run(function($http, $rootScope, $location, sessionService){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
        if(!sessionService.isLogged() && next.requireLogin){
            $location.path("/login");
        }

        if(sessionService.isLogged()){
            if(next.controller !== "LoginCtrl"){
                $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + sessionService.getToken();
            }
        } 
    });

});
```

When i remove this interceptor, i can see my alert('error'). I guess i have to fix/end the interceptor and evertything will works fine.