# $location.path not working from http interceptor

Tags: angularjs

this is your fairly straight-forward setup, I have an http interceptor that's looking for 401s, if found the user is redirected to the login page:

```
function($location, $q)
{
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        requestError: function(request){
            return $q.reject(request);
        },
        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (response)
        {
            if (response && response.status === 401)
            {
                $location.path('/login');                    
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };

}
```

The problem is the `$location.path('/login')` call doesn't seem to work, the path is completely disregarded and I remain on the route (albeit a blank page) I was on when my session expires. One possible workaround is to use the traditional `window.location = '/#!/login';` but I find this to be less than ideal. I also find that if I remove the `return $q.reject(response);` line I get it working, BUT this introduces another error where the response's data property cannot be found (solution discussed here: [Angular.js $http.post TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589752/angular-js-http-post-typeerror-cannot-read-property-data-of-undefined)).

I am running angular 1.2.21.

Any ideas on what might be going on here? Reverting to window.location isn't the end of the world but I'd love a nice tidy solution to this mystery :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499323/location-path-doesnt-change-in-a-factory-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

I'm not sure but looks like `$location.path(...)` does not change location because app waits until all promises will be resolved, and the promise inside the interceptor is rejected (`return $q.reject(response);`)

In my case the service that does http request is placed inside the `resolve` section of UI-router state, so I can use `$stateChangeError` event to handle the error.
(for ngRoute use $routeChangeError event)

Hope this can help you :)

NB The backend of my app return custom error messages in 401 response body

PS There must be some better solution

**UPDATE:**

More universal workaround:

interceptor inside the module.config

```
...
responseError: function (response) {
    if (response && response.status === 401) {
        $rootScope.$emit('loginRequired');
    }

    return $q.reject(response);
}
...
```

and event handler somewhere in module.run section

```
$rootScope.$on('loginRequired', function() {
    $location.path('/login');
});
```

(I've tested handler with `$state.go('login')` but `$location.path('/login');` should works too :) )

Comment: The similar soulution: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/xhr-interceptor-in-an-angularjs-web-app (the difference is that the `.success()` callback is used)

Comment: My code work with $state.go('login') but $location.path is not work